# Varchar and Date Incompatible SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation

I have written the below SQL and trying to do it using variables.

```
--Select DB
USE [gkretail_master]

--Declare Varibles
DECLARE @StartDate DATE;
DECLARE @EndDate DATE;
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(8000);

--Set Variables
SET @StartDate = '2018-05-23 00:00:00.000';
SET @EndDate = '2018-05-23 23:59:00.000' 
SET @SQL =
        'SELECT
            RETAIL_STORE_NUMBER AS ''Store Number'',
            DESCRIPTION_1 AS ''Store Name'', 
            CAST(SUM(BRUTTOGES) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS ''Total Taken''
        FROM [GKRETAIL_MASTER].[GK_BONKOPF] 
            JOIN [gkretail_master].[GK_STORE_DATA] ON [GK_BONKOPF].[ID_BSNGP] = [GK_STORE_DATA].[ID_BSNGP]
        WHERE 
            AKTDAT > '+ @StartDate +' 
        AND 
            AKTDAT < '+ @EndDate +' 
        GROUP BY [GK_BONKOPF].[ID_BSNGP], DESCRIPTION_1, RETAIL_STORE_NUMBER';

EXECUTE(@SQL);
```

It however returns the error:

> The data types varchar and date are incompatible in the add operator.

I have done some googling and tried to resolve it using both CAST and convert but it flags up more errors.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which database are you running this on?

Comment: What is the schema for the database tables concerned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exactly.  That is one important reason why you should pass parameters using `sp_executesql`:

```
SET @SQL =
        'SELECT
            RETAIL_STORE_NUMBER AS ''Store Number'',
            DESCRIPTION_1 AS ''Store Name'', 
            CAST(SUM(BRUTTOGES) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS ''Total Taken''
        FROM [GKRETAIL_MASTER].[GK_BONKOPF] 
            JOIN [gkretail_master].[GK_STORE_DATA] ON [GK_BONKOPF].[ID_BSNGP] = [GK_STORE_DATA].[ID_BSNGP]
        WHERE 
            AKTDAT > @StartDate 
        AND 
            AKTDAT < @EndDate 
        GROUP BY [GK_BONKOPF].[ID_BSNGP], DESCRIPTION_1, RETAIL_STORE_NUMBER';

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL,
     N'@StartDate date, @EndDate date',
     @StartDate = @StartDate, @EndDate = @EndDate;
```

Comment: this or use solution from similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028523/working-with-datetime-with-dynamic-query-in-sql-server

Comment: This approach is good as it keeps you away from potential SQL injection patterns.